# IPython Notebook version issue (IPython 0.13)

Tags: ipython, enthought, jupyter-notebook

On my Windows 7 desktop I have IPython version 0.13 installed -- I get version 0.13 notebook's menu etc but when I try to load certain ipynb files - for eg https://github.com/lisa-lab/pylearn2/blob/master/tutorials/multilayer_perceptron.ipynb  I get the message

"An error occurred while loading this notebook. Most likely this notebook is in a newer format than is supported by this version of IPython. This version can load notebook formats v3 or earlier."

even though there are other recent nbs that work, for eg http://epi.whoi.edu/esr/GIS_GRASS-R_Example.ipynb

Any idea as to what I ought to be doing

UPDATE:
To rectify this I uninstalled my previous epd installation and reinstalled epd 7.3.2. I may have had some bad state on my Windows system because after that install, when I did 'ipython notebook' on command line, I would get a message saying Windows couldnt find the file ipython-scripts.py or some such and the notebook would never come up. I again uninstalled and 'rm -rf'd the Python27 directory and reinstalled epd 7.3.2 using msiexec /i as Admin. Now IPython notebook does launch. However in order to retry with the below issue, when I try to 'click here' load the .ipynb file from a directory of .ipynbs I have, it doesnt seem to work -- 
Isnt this how its supposed to be done?

UPDATE 2:
I restarted IPython with the command "ipython notebook --pylab inline --notebook-dir="C:\Users\Rakesh\IDATA" so it now has the .ipynbs in the notebook directory. Now when I select and click on the .ipynbs it does seem to load correctly. However I was wondering why the 'Click here' attempt above tanked..

Comment: a common mistake when downloading from github is to downlaod the GitHub page, rather than the notebook itself.  If you open the notebook in a text editor, does it look like HTML (lots of `<tag>`) or JSON (like a Python dict, lots of `{`)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm unable to reproduce this, on Windows 7, with IPython v0.13.  Are you sure that your ipynb file has been downloaded correctly?

Comment: Notebook looks also fine on nbviewer http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/lisa-lab/pylearn2/master/tutorials/multilayer_perceptron.ipynb would suggest to also update to 0.13.1